# simple vs full lucene syntax in azure search

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

What is the difference between 'full' and 'simple' lucene query syntax in Azure search ? Is there any performance advantage to use 'simple'query type?.

For example, in my expirience these two queries return the same result:

$filter=search.ismatch('w/ tip', 'Trim', **'simple'**, 'all')

$filter=search.ismatch('w/ tip', 'Trim', **'full'**, 'all')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

query type full is used for advanced query constructs like regular expressions, proximity search, fuzzy and wildcard search.

According to the official doc, this extra power comes with additional processing requirements so you should expect a slightly longer execution time when comparing with query type simple.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-simple-examples